# Is it possible use integer array values as index of other integer array?

Tags: arrays, c, indexing

I am here developing a program to find the occurrence of the integers in an integer array. But, I am ending with the error of segmentation fault.
Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5},count[10]={0},i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++)
    {
        int x;
        x=a[i];
        count[x]=count[x]+1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(count);i++)
    {
        if(count[i]!=0)
        {
            printf("\n %d:%d",i,count[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` measures size in bytes, not number of elements.  Your loop iterates 40 times and way overruns the arrays.  You could write `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)` instead, and likewise for `sizeof(count)`.

Comment: Read a good C programming book (like [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).... to be invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)....). Read the documentation of *every* function you did not define, e.g. of [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)...).

Comment: If allowed, read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer C standard. It defines "what is possible" and important notions like [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Download, then take inspiration from the source code of *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) such as  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Avoid [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: You could have added `printf("sizeof(a) is %zd\n", sizeof(a));` in your source code before the first `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

To get the array size you need to divide the size of the array by the size of its element

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
```

`sizeof` gives the size of the object in **bytes** not elements

Comment: Thanks for the resultant code:
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5},count[10]={0},i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
    {
        int x;
        x=a[i];
        count[x]=count[x]+1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(count)/sizeof(count[0]);i++)
    {
        if(count[i]!=0)
        {
            printf("\n %d:%d",i,count[i]);
        }
    }
}